# ezvcard PHOTO Encoding on V4

Tags: vcf-vcard

vcard 0.11.3 with Kotlin.

We create an avatar Photo

```
val photo = Photo(photoStream, ImageType.JPEG)
with(photo.parameters) {
  encoding = Encoding.B
  type = ImageType.JPEG.value.toUpperCase()
}
```

and when we write the card using

```
Ezvcard.write(vcard).version(VCardVersion.V4_0).go()
```

I expect to see in the String:

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=jpeg:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI...
```

but just get:

```
PHOTO:data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the format Version 4.
You talk about Version 3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).